# Insert space in current cursor location

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextrange

I've searched stackoverflow and the web, but couldn't find something that works. I have a `UIButton` that inserts a space when you click on it, now it adds the space at the end of the `UITextField` even when the cursor is in the middle.

How can I add space at current cursor position with `UIButton` click?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS 5+, try

```
[textField replaceRange:[textField selectedTextRange] withText:@" "];
```